# Missing HttpOnly Attribute in Session Cookie

Tags: java, security, jsp, jsessionid, httponly

in `sign.jsp`, I have written the following so that, if a user is already logged in then immediately he would be forwarded to his `home page`

```
<%
try{

HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);

if(session1.getAttribute("authenticated")!=null &&  
 session1.getAttribute("authenticated").equals(true))
{
response.sendRedirect("userhome.jsp");
}
else{

// users have to login here
}
%>
```

Security scan is telling that `Missing HttpOnly Attribute in Session Cookie` in `sign.jsp`.

If i will set:  `<Context useHttpOnly="true">
                    ...
                </Context>`

in : `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.20\conf`

then will my problem be solved or what else i have to do? Any suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: which Servlet version you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using Servlet 3.0. Than
In Servlet 3.0 (Java EE 6) introduced a standard way to configure HttpOnly attribute for the session cookie, applying the following configuration in web.xml

```
<session-config>
 <cookie-config>
  <http-only>true</http-only>
 </cookie-config>
<session-config>
```

Comment: only this much i have to do in `web.xml` or some modification is required in `jsp/servlet` too?

Comment: +1 and i also accepted your answer Riddhish, i am using javaEE 6 so i think your method will work

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this article https://access.redhat.com/solutions/338313

I think you have to set

```
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true">
  <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

attributes in "$PROFILE\deploy\jbossweb.sar\context.xml"